# Value Animation not working on 5.0 Lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-animation

I am running a sample of android expend animation. It is using value animation. I have two devices , one is samsang  note 3 with 4.4.2 and other is galaxy s5 with 5.0 .The animation working fine on note 3 mobile but not working on galaxy s5 mobile. Is this an Os depended issue or something else. Any idea would be a great help. Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
LinearLayout mLinearLayoutHeader;
ValueAnimator mAnimator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.expandable);
    //mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mLinearLayoutHeader = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header);

    //Add onPreDrawListener
    mLinearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            mLinearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            mLinearLayout.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
        //  mAnimator.setDuration(1000);
            mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, mLinearLayout.getMeasuredHeight());
            return true;
        }
    });


    mLinearLayoutHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mLinearLayout.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                expand();
            }else{
                collapse();
            }
        }
    });
}


private void expand() {
    //set Visible
    mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    /* Remove and used in preDrawListener
    final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    mLinearLayout.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

    mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, mLinearLayout.getMeasuredHeight());
    */
    mAnimator.setDuration(1000);
    mAnimator.start();
}

private void collapse() {
    int finalHeight = mLinearLayout.getHeight();

    ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(finalHeight, 0);

    mAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            //Height=0, but it set visibility to GONE
            mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
        }
    });
    mAnimator.start();
}


private ValueAnimator slideAnimator(int start, int end) {

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);


    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            //Update Height
            int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mLinearLayout.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = value;
            mLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
    return animator;
}

}
```

Here is my sdk version in both gradle and manifest.

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Here is my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/color"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/color_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/color_height"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text=""
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/clickme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/clickme" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/expandable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Provide R.layout.activity_main code aslo

Comment: what does `"but not working on s5"` mean?

Comment: Xml added. pskink kindly check I have updated the question.

Comment: add some `Log.d` inside `onAnimationUpdate`

Comment: @pskink What would be the benefit of it ?

Comment: did you ever debug any code?

Comment: @pskink i have done 6 android applications. I m just ask what you think would be the issue. Why referring me to the logs? What would be the problem according to you.

Comment: did you add some Log.d calls?

Comment: that's great, and ... ?